# Google Charts how to change x axis lable orientation

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

I'm using a column Chart from Google Charts.

How do I diagonally align label in google chart on x or y axis?

Thanks!

Comment: Please out line what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do them by

```
var options = { title: "X_axis", hAxis: { direction:-1, slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:45 } };
```